# Parse Query where two keys equal one value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to perform a query that returns objects of the same value for two different keys. I can do `query.selectKeys(keys: [AnyObject])` but I can't specify a value. And I can't do two separate `query.whereKey(key, equalTo:)` because two constraints act as an AND operator, not OR.

Any way to achieve this, or must I do two separate queries altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to combine several `PFQuery` into a single `PFQuery` based on `OR`. A simple example can be seen here where I created a new table called `ORQueries` and filled it with some dummy data. Each object has a `foo` and a `bar` property which contain an integer.

```
func orQueryTheDummyData() {
    let fooIsThreeQuery = PFQuery(className: "ORQueries").whereKey("foo", equalTo: 3)
    let barIsFiveQuery = PFQuery(className: "ORQueries").whereKey("bar", equalTo: 5)

    let combinedQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([fooIsThreeQuery, barIsFiveQuery])

    combinedQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in
        println("result: \(result)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. Thanks though! I'll give it to you anyway ;)